# blocking packets for a non established connection on freebsd pf

Tags: freebsd, pf

For a freebsd pf firewall; I want it to block packets for non established connections. For example , the attacker should not send Reset packets for an unknown not-yet-established connection.

In Linux it is easy to do

```
-d targethost -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow new state establishments and block any other thing except for packets for the established state (ESTABLISHED)

I think freebsd pf should also work like this. Does pf has anything such? Do you think the ruleset below should allow Reset packets for a nonestablished connection?

```
# pfctl -sr -vvv
@0 pass in log (all) quick from <administrators:4> to any flags S/SA synproxy state
  [ Evaluations: 423       Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 4     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 25567 State Creations: 4     ]
@1 block drop log (all) quick inet6 all
  [ Evaluations: 419       Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 25567 State Creations: 0     ]
@2 block drop log (all) quick from <blacklist:0> to any
  [ Evaluations: 419       Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 25567 State Creations: 0     ]
@3 pass log (all) quick all flags S/SA keep state
  [ Evaluations: 419       Packets: 103       Bytes: 10941       States: 15    ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 25567 State Creations: 19    ]
```

tcpdump -i pflog0 does not sat aything(pass or block) accepting packets for Reset packets destined for a host behind the firewall.

Comment: I think PF handle this with `flags S/A` for tcp packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the OpenBSD `pf` docs](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#state):

> All pass rules automatically create a state entry when a packet
>   matches the rule. This can be explicitly disabled by using the `no state` option.

So you're already stateful.

And to clarify, FreeBSD occasionally ports `pf` over from OpenBSD, so their documentation applies for core features.